# Cannot connect to PostgreSQL from anywehere except SSH

Tags: java, postgresql, intellij-idea

I have a SSH connection to a remote server with PostgreSQL, which I want to use in my code to insert/update data. I can connect to it via Database connection (In IntelliJ right side --> Database). But how to execute queries to that database using only this SSH connection? Now, I'm trying to access to it via `Driver`:

`postGresConn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbUsername, dbPassword);`

And use it like this:

```
private void loadPostgreDriver() {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void getConnection() {
    try {
        postGresConn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbUsername, dbPassword);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public LinkedList<LinkedList<String>> queryDB(String query) {
    LinkedList<LinkedList<String>> result = new LinkedList<LinkedList<String>>();
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    try {
        statement = postGresConn.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
    /*** More code here ***/
    }
}
```

But my `postgresConnn` fails, because I'm trying to connect to it without SSH, I guess. How to solve it?

Comment: How do you know it’s failing because of SSH? What’s the specific exception that is getting thrown?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need an ssh connection to connect to your remote Postgres database.

SSH connections may be used for remote command line execution, or in certain cases to tunnel TCP/IP traffic.

As I understand in your case, the Postgres port, 5432 on the remote host, is already opened, as you are able to connect using IntelliJ.

Comment: My connection string is: `jdbc:postgresql://hostname/dbName`, but when I'm trying to connect: `The connection attempt failed.` and `connect timed out`

Comment: "connect timed out" means: postgres is not listening on the remote server using TCP/IP socket, or: there is a firewall between the postgres server and your local host. This is in contradiction with " I can connect to it via Database connection (In IntelliJ right side --> Database)" ...